# How can I count occurrences of a value?

Tags: jq, counting

I have found the following way to count values in an arbitrarily structured JSON:

```bash
{
cat <<EOF
{
    "a": 3,
    "b": 4,
    "c": 3,
    "d": {
        "e": 3
    },
    "f": 6
}
EOF
} | jq '[..
        | if type == "object"
          then select(.value)
          else .
          end
        ] | map(select(. == 3)) | length'
```

Is there a shorter way to count recursively in an arbitrarily structured JSON?

I am wondering whether maybe I need to use `walk`, but could only find the following and did not know how to count in the end:

```bash
{
cat <<EOF
{
    "a": 3,
    "b": 4,
    "c": 3,
    "d": {
        "e": 3
    },
    "f": 6
}
EOF
} | jq '..
        | walk(if type == "object"
               then to_entries
                    | map(select(.value))
                    | from_entries
               else .
               end
        )
        | (. == 3)'
```

Yielding:

```
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For counting, it's often a good idea to use the generic filter:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+1);

count(tostream | select(length==2 and .[1] == $value))
```

where $value is the value of interest.

In this particular case, you could also use jq's `--stream` command-line option, e.g.

```
jq -n --argjson 3 --stream -f program.jq
```

where program.jq contains the above def followed by:

```
count(inputs | select(length==2 and .[1] == $value))
```

Using the --stream option would be advantageous if the source included a giant JSON value.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I sort of understand what the code does through taking parts of it and looking at what comes out. It seems that `count` is not the built-in `count`. That seems noteworthy. Or using a different name. What I do not yet understand is, why `reduce` needs to create a `$x`. Is that simply a `jq` requirement for the syntax to be valid?

Comment: You could use any other allowed name for the “reduce” variable, e.g. $_

Comment: I understand that. I guess you are saying, that no matter what its name, one has to have a variable there, even when it is not used.

Answer (score 3):

You could comb through the stream representation, filter out matching items, and count on the fly:

```bash
jq 'reduce tostream[1] as $v (0; if $v == 3 then .+1 else . end)'
```

Likewise, you could iterate recursively using `..`, and consider only `scalars` (or `numbers`):

```bash
jq 'reduce (.. | scalars) as $v (0; if $v == 3 then .+1 else . end)'
```

Or move the condition into the iteration generator, so you can count unconditionally in the body:

```bash
jq 'reduce (.. | select(numbers == 3)) as $_ (0; .+1)'
```